# Does MIT Cheetah uses Series Elastic Actuator?

Tags: actuator

I have been wondering does MIT cheetah purely only use electrical active compliance on it's robot or did they use a Series elastic actuator since they have this webbing tendon?

Comment: `this webbing tendon` .... what are you referring to? .... did you forget to include a picture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the answer is that it doesn't actually use either of those designs.

According to the paper [Proprioceptive Actuator Design in the MIT Cheetah: Impact Mitigation and High-Bandwidth Physical Interaction for Dynamic Legged Robots](http://fab.cba.mit.edu/classes/865.18/motion/papers/mit-cheetah-actuator.pdf) by Patrick M. Wensing *et al*, the MIT Cheetah robot actually uses a *proprioceptive force-control actuator* Design.

The development and design principles that led to that design were described in the earlier paper [Design Principles for Energy Efficient Legged Locomotion and
Implementation on the MIT Cheetah Robot](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/83225552.pdf) by Sangok Seok *et al*.